# How to print a object with constructor from another class (constructor) (java)

Tags: java, object, methods, printing, constructor

I have two classes ("Startup.java" and "Book.java"). 
My goal is to print all object(s) from "Book.java".
To call the `view()` method, I initialized a new 'book-object'. The problem is:
if I call "book.view", it print's '0nullnull0' (I know, it's because of the constructor), I have no idea how to fix it. Here you can see the code:

```
package array;

import java.util.*;

public class Startup{

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Book book = new Book(0, null, null, 0);
        book.view();
    }



package array;

public class Book {

    private int number;
    private String title;
    private String language;
    private int price;

    public Book(int number, String title, String language, int price) {
        this.number = number;
        this.title = title;
        this.language = language;
        this.price = price;
    }

    public void add() {
        Book b1 = new Book(1, "title", "de", 2);
    }

    public void view() {
        System.out.println(number + title + language + price);
    }
}
```

Comment: What do you expect it to print?

Comment: Having a look at your `add` method and your comment "*I know, it's because of the constructor*" makes me think you don't really know yet how Java works. I would highly recommend you to read a tutorial. Your code is btw. doing exactly what would be expected of it. You initialize the values to `0`, `null`, `null` and `0` and exactly that gets printed.

Comment: If the understanding is correct, you want `Startup` to print all objects(instances) created for `Book` class. Is it ?

Comment: I don't see the problem here. The code is doing exactly what it's supposed to :)

Comment: @PaulBenn it's doing what it's written to do, that doesn't mean it's doing what it's supposed to do

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have initialized your object using

```
Book book = new Book(0, null, null, 0);
```

Hence, the output is coming like that.

I think you want the values in your add method (not sure what that method is for?) to be printed.
So, you need to call your constructor with those values.

```
Book book = new Book(1, "title", "de", 2);
book.view();
```

Answer (score 0):

You can print all Book objects by storing the objects in an array and then iterating through the array and call the list function for each Object of the array

```
Book[] bookArray=new book[n];
```

Add your objects to this array

Now iterating through the array you would be able to print all the objects

```
for(int i=0;i<n;i++) {
    bookArray[i].view();
}
```